# If a sequence converges, do its tail terms equal its limit?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

A sequence $(x_n)$ in a metric space $X$ is said to converge if there is a point $x \in X$ such that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is an integer $N$ such that $n \geq N$ implies that $d(x_n, x) < \epsilon$.

I've seen proofs where having found that $d(A,B) < \epsilon$, we state that the choice of $\epsilon$ was arbitrary and thus that $A = B$. I was wondering if we could do the same here and conclude that for $n \geq N$, $x_n = x$. I'd also appreciate an explanation of when we can and cannot make such a conclusion; sometimes it seems like we're just letting $\epsilon$ be $0$ when it suits us.

Comment: No, the $N$ depends on your choice of $\epsilon$. Take $x_{n}=1/n$ in $\mathbb{R}$ for example. It converges to $0$ and the tails are never constant.

Comment: You're never letting $\epsilon = 0$ when it suits you.  It's only that eventually all terms will be arbitrarily close to your limit $x$.  Think of what happens when $x_n = 1/n$ for example.

Comment: That would imply that the sequence is eventually the constant sequence which isn’t always the case. Consider the case where $X$ is the real line and $d$ is the Euclidean metric and the sequence $\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)$. Is it true that there is some integer $N$ such that for every $n \geq N$, we have $0 = \frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: If $d(A,B)<e$ for every POSITIVE $e$ then $d(A,B)=0$ and therefore $A=B.$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\left\{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$ is a sequence of non-zero terms which converges to $0$.

When we have something like $d(x,y) < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$, we never "let $\epsilon = 0$". Rather we are able to deduce that $x = y$. For if $x \ne y$, then $d = d(x,y) > 0$, which would contradict our assumption (i.e. $\epsilon = d$ would be a positive number for which $d(x,y) < \epsilon$ fails to hold). Therefore, it must be the case that $x = y$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is my intuition correct in that if $x \neq y$, there would be a lower bound for $\epsilon$?